# Probability Library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to create a library for dealing with probability in C#. My current system takes an ordered array of probabilities as an input then generates a random double. It then accumulates each double in the array until the accumulated values are greater than the randomly selected one. Like this (`Samples` is the array of probabilities and `Sample` is the random value) :

```
int i;

for 
(
    (i, double accumulator) = (0, Samples[0].Probability); 
    i < Samples.Length && accumulator > Sample; 
    accumulator += Samples[++i].Probability

);

return i==Samples.Length? null:Samples[i];
```

Is this the fastest way of doing this? Also are there any good well-known probability libraries out there?

Comment: The question [Can I foreach over an array of structs without copying the elements in C# 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58069669/880990) has an interesting answer showing some benchmark results. Using `.AsSpan()` can speed up the loop and even using `foreach` instead of `for` can do so (which was quite unexpected for me). But every case is different. So, the only way to speed up your code is to do benchmarks with different code variants. Use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) for your benchmarks.

Comment: Ok Thank you I was looking into spans but I read somewhere that there isn't much of a performance increase when iterating over arrays and I would have to resort to SIMD instructions for any noticeable speedups?

Comment: Since the order of the evaluation is important (you stop iterating when `accumulator > Sample`) I do not see a way to do this in parallel. Btw., the condition in the for should be `i < Samples.Length && accumulator <= Sample` because this is the condition for not stopping.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach has a time complexity of *O*(*⁡n*)., where *n* is the length of the `Samples` array. This is because you're iterating through the array to find the appropriate sample. If you're dealing with a large number of samples, this could become a bottleneck.

#### Alternative Approaches

1. **Binary Search**: If your probabilities are sorted, you could use binary search to find the appropriate sample, reducing the time complexity to *O*(log *n*).
2. **Alias Method**: This method allows you to sample from a discrete probability distribution in *O*(1) time after *O*(*n*) preprocessing time.

#### Existing Libraries

1. **MathNet.Numerics**: This is a well-known library for numerical computing in .NET, and it includes some probability distribution functions.
2. **Accord.NET**: This is another comprehensive framework for scientific computing in .NET, which includes probability and statistical functions.
3. **Meta.Numerics**: This library offers advanced mathematical and statistical functions, including some for probability.
   mark for performance.

Comment: In terms of binary search would that work since I am dealing with a randomly selected doubles. For example if I had two very precise doubles and my binary search algorithm needed to place the randomly selected sample in between them surely a linear search would have better performance? Maybe wanting probability to such accuracy is quite rare so the algorithm would have low average running time. However I will definitely look into the alias method in more depth as this seems best for my needs thank you for your help and including the libraries :)